# Using php to export individual tables from cpanel's mysql database to csv format

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cpanel, export-to-csv

I just started learning php a few days ago and I'm struggling to export table info from the mysql databases to csv format. I've looked around a lot and I've written various php scripts to try this, but none of them function correctly. The tables all have different rows and columns (i.e., one table may have headers of name, age, address, while another table may have headers of hobbies, gender, and race). For now, I'd just be satisfied with any help I can get to just outputting the information correctly so I can understand how it's done.

This is just one of the examples of my failed attempts:

```
<?php
    // mysql database connection details
    $host = "";
    $user = "";
    $password = "";
    $db = "";

    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select * from db";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct aside from the fact that your database credentials aren't set. Is anything being written to the file?

Comment: for `$sql = "select * from db";`, is "db" a table name? (it should be)

Comment: @KevinP I left out the credentials just because I'm posting this publicly for help, haha. But yes, the original file has the username, password, and host info all inputted.

Comment: @AlexTartan Oh, it's not! I'm sorry, I thought select * from db would attempt to loop through all the table names inside the database. I'll change this to a table name and see if that fixes my issue.

Comment: Is anything being written to the file? Have you ran print_r($row); to make sure results are being returned?

Comment: @KevinP I have not ran that. I'm assuming I just write that line in after fputcsv inside the while loop?

Comment: After changing the db to an actual table name, I'm just getting this error now: 
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$connection' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\cronjob\TestJob4.php on line 9

Comment: Check semicolons `;` on line 8

Comment: @AlexT Semicolons appear to be fine, not much has changed in the code except me changing the table name. Line 8 is just a comment. Uhhh, after running it again on wamp though, now I'm just getting a completely white screen.

Comment: A white screen in your case would be fine. You're not outputing anything _on the screen_. Check the file for contents. Also, you should enable all error reporting.

Comment: Yeah, I added  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at line 7 to check if anything was wrong, but no error popped up. It never initiated a download for the csv file however so I can't check it. One of my other attempts, even if it failed, downloaded a failed csv file with weird encoded errors.

Comment: that script won't give you any download. it will just create a local file with the table contents. check the file locally

Comment: @AlexTartan Sorry, this is a really dumb question but I can't find the test.csv it was supposed to create? I just changed the name as well to make it stand out from the rest of the failed test.csv's. Where would I search for the file that the script makes?

Comment: without know anything else, it's hard to tell (may be next to this script, may be in some other location). Use an absolute path like '/tmp/test.csv'. Or do `echo __FILE__`; at the top and check that location.

Comment: /tmp/test.csv gave me a ridiculously large number of errors, haha. All pretty much resembling 
( ! ) Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\cronjob\TestJob4.php on line 19. 

Is it possible for us to create a discussion chat or for me to e-mail you to avoid extending this in the comment section too much?

Comment: join here  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149038/q-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-45064418

Comment: It appears as if I need 20 reputation to actually speak in chat.

Comment: I think I might need to change permission to write to this folder, but I'm not entirely sure?